# output$loc2 <- renderInfoBox({ : object 'output' not found

Tags: r, shiny

I want to render infobox in shinyApp.
I am getting error **"output$loc2 <- renderInfoBox({ : object 'output' not found"** on below code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(width = "1260px", 
        tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                    tabPanel(h5("Labtest"), 
                             fluidRow(
                               radioButtons("Ben2", "Details:", 
c("Hypertension", "RBS", "HB", "Malaria"), inline = T),
                               infoBoxOutput("loc2", width = 960)))))))
server <- shinyServer(
output$loc2 <- renderInfoBox({
if(input$Ben2 == "Hypertension") {
box(width='100%', h3("Hypertension"),
infoBox(100, "Total", icon = icon('heartbeat'), width = 3, color = 
"orange", fill = T))          
} else{if(input$Ben2 == "RBS"){
infoBox(30, "Normal",  "Cummulative", icon = icon('heartbeat'), 
width = 3, color = "green", fill = T)
}
else {if(input$Ben2 == "HB"){
infoBox(30, "Pre-Hypertension", "Cummulative", icon = icon('heartbeat'), 
width = 3, color = "yellow", fill = T)
} else{
infoBox(40, "Hypertension", "Cummulative", icon = icon('heartbeat'), width = 
3, color = "red", fill = T)
}}
}}    
))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone help me on this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server <- function(input, output, session) { instead of shinyServer(

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the answer works fine. I closed the shinyApp, again run the code, once again getting same error. Why such error comes again ? Is there particular area I need to look into?

Comment: do you mean after doing the modification it has works, then you close your app and run again and it doesn't work anymore? what's the error then?

Answer (score 0):

Now the logic works properly after closing and rerun it.